# ERROR: Could not find 'wxe_driver.so'

Tags: erlang, ubuntu-10.04, erlang-otp

I got this error on my ubuntu when I run debugger:start().

```
Erlang R14B02 (erts-5.8.3) [source] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> debugger:start().

=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Feb-2012::17:57:27 ===
ERROR: Could not find 'wxe_driver.so' in: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/wx-0.98.9/priv
{ok,<0.36.0>}
```

I want to know how to fix the error in order to use debugger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the default erlang running on ubuntu? Unfortunately there is no longer any erlang-wx package in ubuntu, see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/erlang/+bug/438365) for a discussion on why.

I would recommend downloading the deb package from [here](http://www.erlang-solutions.com/section/132/erlang-otp-packages) or just building erlang from source.