# Erlang debugger error: Could not find 'wxe_driver.so'

Tags: macos, erlang, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I can see the following error report when I start up the debugger.

```
2> debugger:start().

=ERROR REPORT==== 23-Jan-2014::11:59:08 ===
ERROR: Could not find 'wxe_driver.so' in: /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R16B03/lib/erlang/lib/wx-1.1.1/priv
{ok,<0.42.0>}
```

The debugger window still starts despite the error report.

Why the error? Will it cause debugger problem down the road?

Erlang runtime is installed by homebrew. Version number is R16B03

Comment: related to this question perhaps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274875/error-could-not-find-wxe-driver-so

Comment: @Berzemus Not exactly. Different platform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find a solution:

```
brew install wxmac
```

It works with erlang R16B03

Comment: Thanks! Note: you then need to re-install Erlang. I'm not sure if any special switches were used (I used [asdf](https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf)). Maybe none are needed (if the binaries are found they are used).